# How to open native emoji keyboard on button click?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events

I'm having a problem with opening native emoji keyboard on button click.

After research, I'm not sure how to programatically change input type to be emoji keyboard.

Is that even possible to do?

So basically, I have EditText where I have Button, which on click needs to open native emoji keyboard.

Thanks on answers!

Comment: In android stock there is no Emoji keyboard

Comment: `android:inputType="textShortMessage"` gives u emoji keyboard

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having a problem with opening native emoji keyboard on button click.

There is no requirement for the device to have an input method editor (soft keyboard) offering emoji. There is no requirement for the user to be using an input method editor that offers emoji.

> I'm not sure how to programatically change input type to be emoji keyboard

You don't.

Via attributes like `android:inputType`, you can suggest certain behaviors to the user's chosen input method editor. Those are suggestions, not commands; the input method editor does not have to honor anything you request via `android:inputType`.

However, you cannot change the behavior of the user's chosen input method editor via a button click. What the input method editor offers is between the user and the input method editor.